# Windows batch file && operator

Tags: windows, bash, batch-file

In bash I can write this:

```
#!/bin/sh
ant debug && adb install -r bin/Rocher-debug.apk
```

But I have a similar windows batch file, and currently it does this:

```
ant debug
adb install -r bin/Rocher-debug.apk
```

So, if "ant debug" fails, it will still run "adb install," and that's not ideal. Do any of you guys know how to do an && equivalent in this situation?

I really have to sit down and properly learn windows scripting some day soon, since I'll be doing a lot of windows work in a few months. But for now a quick answer would be awesome :-)

Comment: While you are learning Windows batch scripting, check out PowerShell too.

Answer (score 12):

In cmd.exe the `&&` operator should work essentially the same way, provided your program returns error codes correctly.

```
ant debug && adb install -r bin/Rocher-debug.apk
```

Should work.

You can test this the following way:

```
ant debug
echo %errorlevel%
```

If this returns zero when it succeeded and non-zero otherwise, then you can use the exact same `&&` that you use in bash.

Answer (score 0):

Check the *ant debug* success value in Windows `ant debug; echo %errorlevel%` and then use: `if errorlevel <prev_value>  adb install ...`. Most likely the success value will be 0.